# Node.js / Mocha / Supertest REST api -- a del() stopped working after I added a second suite

Tags: node.js, rest, mocha.js, supertest

so I've got a model I'm trying to test. It has custom endpoints as well as the standard REST endpoints. I built a suite to test the standard ops. First I posted, then I upserted(a put w/o an id...basically a post), then I got. Finally I deleted the entry created when I posted, and just clean up after myself I put in an after hook to delete the point I had upserted. This worked and it was good.

Then, in the same file I added another suite, this one testing my custom endpoints. Now my hook that was supposed to delete the upserted point failed. This was not good. I tried wrapping my test for delete in a new describe statement, but again it didn't work. Eventually I did away w/ the hook altogether and just sent 2 .del calls and it still didn't work. I'm at my wits end. Please let me know if you can figure out why this isn't working and how to make it work. Thank you in advance!

Here is my code:

```
var request = require('supertest');
var app = require('../server');
var chai = require('chai');
var chance = require('chance').Chance();
var assert= require('assert');

function json(verb, url) {
  return request(app)[verb](url)
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/);
}
describe('Testing standard REST endpoints-(CREATE, GET,PUT, DELETE)', function() {

//This suite tests the CREATE functionality
            var ptOneID;
            var lat1 =chance.latitude({fixed: 7, min: 41, max: 42});
            var lng1 = chance.longitude({fixed:7, min: -88, max:-87});
            it('should post a new point', function(done) {
                var pt1 = new app.loopback.GeoPoint({lat: lat1, lng: lng1});
                json('post', '/api/Points')
                .send({
                    location: pt1,
                 })
                .expect(200)
                .end(function(err, res) {
            ptOneID= res.body.id;
                    done();
                 });
               });

//This test preforms a put with out an id-- an upsert
         var lat5 =chance.latitude({fixed: 7, min: 41, max: 42});
         var lng5 = chance.longitude({fixed:7, min: -88, max:-87}); 
         var ptTwoID  
         it('should preform an UPSERT since were not specifying ID', function(done) {
             var pt5 = new app.loopback.GeoPoint({lat: lat5, lng: lng5});
             json( 'put','/api/Points/' )

             .send({
                location: pt5,          
             })
          .end(function(err, res) {
         var updatedPoint = res.body;
             ptTwoID = updatedPoint.id;
             done();
            })
          });

         it('should return a list of all points', function(done) {
             json('get', '/api/Points')
             .expect(200)
             .end(function(err, res) {
                 var points = res.body;
                 assert(Array.isArray(points));
                 assert.equal(points.length, 2, 'array length incorrect');
                 done();
      });
  });
//originally I didnt have the delete tests wrapped in a describe I added it to see if it changed anything
     describe('DELETE has its own suite', function() {

//Delete the point
       it('should DELETE the Point created by our POST test', function(done){
       json('del', '/api/Points/' + ptOneID)
       .end(function(err, res) {  
    assert.equal(res.status, 204, 'delete failed');
            done();
        })
      });
it('should DELETE the Point we upserted',function(done){
           json('del', '/api/Points'+ ptTwoID)
      .end(function(err, res) {  
           assert.equal(res.status, 204, 'upsert delete failed');
               done();
       });
     });

  it('testing to see if posted point is still there', function(done){              
      json('get', '/api/Points/' + ptOneID)
      .end(function(err, res) {
          assert.equal(res.status, 404, 'posted point not deleted unsure emoticon');
          done();
      })
    });
//this part was originally wrapped in an after hook, and worked perfectly until I added the describe for custom endpoints 
it('testing to see if upserted point is still there', function(done){              
      json('get', '/api/Points/' + ptTwoID)
      .end(function(err, res) {
          assert.equal(res.status, 404, 'upserted pt not deleted unsure emoticon');
          done();
      })
    });

          });    
            });

    //This suite tests the beforeSave behavior
describe('Testing Custom endpt', function() {
     blah blah blh

        });
```

One last interesting thing: When I try to do the upsert delete, the delete returns a 404, meaning not found, however the get returns a 200 status meaning it was successfully found. Please please let me know what is going on here.